# Deeplink does not open the app from Gmail

Tags: android, android-deep-link

We are trying to implement deepLink from a Gmail in our app. I add following code to my Manifest file :

```
         <activity
            android:name="io.fetchcar.archapp.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_fetch">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="fetch" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

In the Gmail we have following button with html code :

```
<a href="fetch://" class="link" blank="_target" alt="Fetch App">Fetch A Car Now</a>
```

But when we click on the button from `Gmail`, it does not open the app.

The thing is if we open it as a web page in the browser and click on `Fetch A Car Now` button, it opens our app as expected.

Is it any limitation to open our app with Deeplink from Gmail ?

Comment: Deeplink support might be turned off by default for Gmail, the way it is for Firefox and Samsung's browser.